# mPDF: How to fill untill the end of page

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mpdf

Is there any way in mPDF (using html) to fill the rest of page with a particular line (in my case a line of dots) repeated over and over? And then start on the next page with some other text?

Context: I am making a document to be printed and handed out to people. Sometimes I want the rest of the current page to be filed with lines containing dots - a place for notes to be written down. Then I want start a new chapter on a new page

EDIT: I am generating the contents of the document programatically, so I can't just add lines manually to fit the desired number of lines

Comment: mPDF is great. Now mPDF supports addition of HTML very well. Write a HTML with horisontal lines = <hr> Then add this to your page using addHTML. <hr> tag even supports dotted line.

Comment: I presume you mean `WriteHTML` - that is what I am doing. Thanks for the `<hr>` tip, I was using just plain dots, but this is better. However, I don't see how your advice solves the main problem - add lines until the end of page and no more (added clarification about text being generated to the question). Also, I kind of need to write the whole document at once, so using HTML only is prefered

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. The number of lines can be different. Can you not just add a lot of lines, and then not bother if they are too many. The page just may disregard anything going outside the bottom.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `<hr>`'s are then page-broken onto the next page.